# Why do I get "cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing React?

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with importing React in my `app.js`

As you can see on the title I always get that when I import React or react-dom, I tried putting `type="module"` but the jsx doesn't work. I installed react and react-dom using the command: `npm install react react-dom --save-dev`

Do you guys encountered something like this?